# How do I get something into a rectangle without space for non-existent descenders?

Tags: math-mode

This is what I have:

```
$\begin{array}{@{}|@{\,}l@{}}\hline2\end{array}$
```

[image: Bad Descender]

I want it to be very similar, except I don't want the line on the left to descend below the 2.  I don't really even want it to descend if the 2 is replaced with something that *has* descenders.  I don't care if the end result uses an array like I have, or if there is some better, more efficient way to do this.  I just want to make a macro that puts a line over and to the left of some arbitrary text, without descending below the baseline unnecessarily or at all.  Ultimately this is to be used for math.

Comment: please say something about the height of the rule at the top.  should it always be the same height, or could it vary, say, if only "a" were the entire expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newcommand{\lyet}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}% no added height
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% no intercolumn padding
  \begin{array}[b]{|l}
  \hline
  % some room above
  \rule{0pt}{0.2ex}\\
  % small space at the sides
  \mspace{1mu}\smash[b]{#1}\mspace{1mu}
  \end{array}%
  \vphantom{#1}% fix the depth
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

$\lyet{2}+\lyet{x+y-d}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the result depends on the font, but the digits in computer modern are slightly shorter than letters with an ascender, so the top rule over the "2" isn't at the same height as the one over the longer expression.  the same would be true if the latter string were "x + y - z", or even (surprise!) "x - y - z" (which gets the same resulting height as "x + y + z").  better to establish a consistent height.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That could be, but the OP's opinion is needed. With `\lyet{x}` the upper bar would be lower.  I'm not surprised about the height being the same for `x+y+z` and `x-y-z`. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

As long as the content is only [regular-height] numbers or letters...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\zz[1]{\rule{.4pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-.4pt}\overline{\mkern2mu #1\vphantom{0}}}
\begin{document}
$\zz{3}$ and $\zz{345}, \zz{a}$
\end{document}
```

[image]